# Is there a way to backtrack from a breakpoint in a debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging

Is there some debug tool or reasonable technique that allows to "step back" in the debugger from a break point, similarly how you "step into" or "skip over" - other than just stack trace? Tracing a fault condition to its source, by moving backwards. For example, the debugger recording a "trail" of how the program was executed, or creating "save points" letting you jump, say, a hundred steps before the breakpoint and trace from there?

---

Let's take a typical scenario: I have a function that processes data created in dozens of places of the program, and does it frequently, hundreds of times per second. It's called from a general "engine", pulling the data from a storage (queue?) where data providers put it for processing. This function requires input data to be sane, and checks for it being so.

The general idea is that this exception should never happen - all callers should always provide sane input. Yet somewhere there's a bug that occasionally places garbage in the storage.

I can't reasonably put a breakpoint at every single call of the function, because there are hundreds of them before the condition occurs. I can put a breakpoint at the sanity check and stop the execution when input is garbage, but by then the identity of the creator of the garbage is long gone. And plain call hierarchy / stack trace will show we've been called from the engine, which is not at fault. I might include sanity check in the "store" function, but in specific situations it might be that the validity of the data may not be known a'priori, say, the sanity check depending on some conditions that occur only after storage, or being so time-consuming it can't be performed in the producer thread.

Generally, I need to trace a piece of data back from consumption to production. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, [rr](http://rr-project.org/) can do that and supposedly vanilla gdb is also capable of it if you use the right options, though with significant performance costs. Your question, however, is explicitly off-topic on SO. Maybe it is on-topic on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There's also [undodb](http://undo.io/products/undodb/).

Comment: You could also use a more intrusive technique by substituting your enqueue operation to a macro that records the file name and line number in a struct and also copies the data payload to a separate part of memory (let's say some ring buffer somewhere that is "large enough").  Now you can examine that memory post-fact and match it with the producer (e.g. if you also store a unique ID in the queue and the ring buffer).  This approach would also help you pinpoint whether the data is corrupt on entry, or becomes corrupted later by something else.

Comment: What about conditional breakpoints? If the garbage is somewhat deterministic you might be able to check for it at an earlier stage for debugging.